# Why do so many movies feature the Dell Rugged laptop?

Tags: product-placement

I was watching the film *Ant-Man* when I saw a character using a Dell Rugged. I thought it was weird how many different films seem to feature this same laptop. **Why do so many movies feature the Dell Rugged?**

Ant-man 
[image: Ant-man]

Interstellar

[image: interstellar]
Orphan Black

[image: GONE GIRL]

There are hundreds of movies where they are using Dell Rugged, but why? In some cases it can be justified, like in a military action scene, but why would Ant-Man be using one?

Comment: Similarly [Apple products in movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/apple-products-in-movies) and [Why does Arrow have so much Microsoft product placement?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31003/why-does-arrow-have-so-much-microsoft-product-placement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you see such an obvious product in a movie or TV show it's a [product placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_placement). This is when a company pays the filmmaker to include their product in the movie or TV show.

> Product placement, also known as embedded marketing, is a marketing technique where references to specific brands or products are incorporated into another work, such as a film or television program, with specific promotional intent.

It can make some scenes more realistic than having obviously made-up products like soft drinks and cereal boxes. Or, if done poorly, it can look ridiculous, or even bizarre.

A great example of pushback to product placement is the movie [Repo Man](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087995/?ref_=nv_sr_1) where all of the food products are generic with white labels and black type on them. The beer is  simply labeled "Beer" with no branding whatsoever, for example. I think at one point there may have even been cans simply labeled, "Food", if I recall correctly.

Comment: So marvel receive money to do a product  placement, but what kind of persons buy a Dell Rugged ? 

Or the product placement is for the brand and not for the product himself like the rugged laptop ?

Well in fact the only kind of person can buy a Dell Rugged is for building constructions,army, adventurers, or maybe people like that style of laptop (Like me) . 

But do you think than Dell paid Marvel to do a product placement just for the Brand or the product himself ?

Comment: @DavidMartins Advertising the brand and advertising the specific product is not and either/or proposition.  Any publicity this placement might generate is a win for Dell.

Comment: I think Steve-O is right. Additionally, I'm sure there are some contracts that dictate a specific product be used and others that allow the director some freedom. In "Night at the Museum: Battle of the Smithsonian",  there's a character from the 1940's named Joey who's really good with radios. At the end, he's  in his bedroom working on a new radio when his mother calls him for dinner. She says something like, "Joey Motorola, get down here and eat your dinner!" I doubt Motorola specified their  placement should be like that.They  probably just paid for some  placement and that's what they got.